# Chrome load script queueing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We use requirejs to modular js files. When access our site, the page will wait long time to display in chrome.

Press F12, see load one script cost too many times

[image]

See queueing description [Detail](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing)

[image]

But between 5000ms and 10000ms only one script is loading

[image]

So how to resolve this, thanks for any help.

// Edit

Only first time load page wait long time. When load complete, press F5 refresh page, it's ok, works as normal, but if we close the chrome browser, then open chrome and access the page, it will wait long time again.

// Add Timeline show

[image]

Comment: look like you have large script, or slow web server (or both). At first time browser load it from server, next time browser get it from cache. Otherwise I can't understand your problem.

Comment: @degr thanks for you reply. 1.the file size is 1.7kb 2.before load this script file, there many other script files, they are not queueing, but when load this script it's queueing 3. we have checked disabled cache to disable chrome cache

Comment: the file is queueing, not create tcp connection yet

Comment: Understand, but there is not enough data. Open dev tools, than open network tab. Search there for `Timeline - start time` column and refresh your browser. Think it should help.

Comment: @degr add timeline picture, only one script is loading, but it was blocked

Comment: It look very weird. Are you sure that it is proper timeline, I mean, there is no excluded images, xhr requests, documents, etc? I mean, is filter setted to `All`?

Comment: @degr Sorry for reply so late. Yes, filter is `All` no other resources load just this one script file

Comment: Absolutely have no idea why it happen. Please write here if you will resolve it. If it happen only in chrome, may be you should report a bug